# If $\lfloor a \rfloor \le b$, what is $a$ less than?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that $\lfloor a \rfloor \le b$. Can I then conclude that $a \le b + 1$?

Is that the most precise way to describe a?

Comment: Slightly more precise: $a < b+1$. But that's as good as it gets if $b$ is an integer. For a non-integer $b$, you can say $a < \lceil b\rceil$.

Comment: @DanielFischer For $b$ any real, you can say $a<\lfloor b\rfloor +1$, of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lfloor a\rfloor\le b$ if and only if $a<b+1$. Note the strict inequality: if $a$ were equal to $b+1$, its floor would be $b+1$, not $b$ or less.

In more detail, $\lfloor a\rfloor=n$ if and only if $n\le a<n+1$, i.e., if and only if $a\in[n,n+1)$. Thus,

$$\{a\in\Bbb R:\lfloor a\rfloor\le b\}=\bigcup_{n\le b}[n,n+1)=(\leftarrow,b+1)\;,$$

the set of all real numbers less than $b+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can conclude $a\leq b+1$. If $a>b+1$ (for contradiction purposes), then what do I know about $\lfloor a \rfloor$?

Edit: As others have said it is not the most precise way to describe $a$, and a similar argument works in that description as well.

Answer (score 0):

If $a-h\leq b$ then $a \leq b+h$, hence $a \leq b+1$ since $h< 1$

Answer (score 0):

Write $a$ as $\lfloor a \rfloor + \{a\}$, where $\lfloor a \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\{a\} \in [0,1)$. We hence have
$$\lfloor a \rfloor \leq b \implies a \leq b +\{a\} \in [b,b+1)$$